# dyplr using Mutate and Case_when with NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I'm using the `mutate` and `case_when` function to create a new variable with the result dependent on whether certain conditions are met.

The following code works until it gets to the NA values.

Running the code is successful, as in it does not produce any error or warning messages, and when I inspect the dataset it has worked where the conditions == 1 or 2, but it has not worked for the NA values.

I have tried putting NA in "" but this doesn't help

```
  mutate(Variable1 = case_when
         (VariableA == 1 & VariableB ==1 ~ result.y,
           VariableA == 1 & VariableB ==2 ~ result.y,
           VariableA == 2 & VariableB ==1 ~ result.y,
           VariableA == 2 & VariableB ==2 ~ result.x,
           VariableA == 2 & VariableB ==NA ~ result.x,
           VariableA == NA & VariableB ==1 ~ result.y,
           VariableA == NA & VariableB ==2 ~ result.y,
           VariableA == NA & VariableB ==NA ~ result.x,
          ))
```

VariableA and VariableB have values of 1, 2 and NA
result.y and result.x are variables already in the dataset

First time posting, and fairly new to using R so apologies if I've not included all the information required. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Sample of Data

```
VariableA   VariableB   result.x        result.y
<dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <chr>           <chr>
1               2      valid postcode   valid postcode
1               2      valid postcode   valid postcode
1               NA     valid postcode   NA
1               NA     partial postcode NA
1               2      valid postcode   valid postcode
1               1      valid postcode   valid postcode
NA             NA      valid postcode   NA
2               2      partial postcode NA
2              NA      valid postcode   NA
2               1      valid postcode   valid postcode
```

Output from

```
> dput(head(Test2))
```

```
structure(list(VariableA = structure(c(NA, NA, 2, NA, 2, 2), label = "[VariableA]--Have you moved in to your current house since June of this year?", format.spss = "F1.0", labels = c(Yes = 1, 
No = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    VariableB = structure(c(NA, NA, 2, NA, 2, NA), label = "[VariableB]-- Have you moved into your current house since January 2021?", format.spss = "F1.0", labels = c(Yes = 1, 
    No = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
    )), result.x = structure(c("vaild postcode", "vaild postcode", 
    "vaild postcode", "vaild postcode", "vaild postcode", "vaild postcode"
    ), label = "[category]--", format.spss = "A16", display_width = 16L), 
    result.y = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use `==` to check if something is `NA`. Try using `is.na(VariableA)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. 
Tried your suggestion and know receiving the following error

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Variable1 = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `` names(message) <- `*vtmp*` ``:
! 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is going on without seeing the data you are working with. Are you able to edit your question with sample data so we can replicate your code?

Comment: It is likely that you that `result.y`, `result.x` and `category.x` have different classes, which will indeed produce the error. Please show us your data using `dput(head(data))`

Comment: Thanks @RichardBerry I've put a sample of the data in the question

Comment: Thanks @Basti I've showed the data using the dput function. I've also edited my original question, there was a typo in the section and 'category.x' is mean't to say result.x. I've tried to simplify the data and forgot to change the cateogory.x to say result.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the example provided, `VariableA` and `VariableB` are of class `dbl+lbl` which cannot be used in a logical with numeric values.

You need to extract the `dbl` information form VariableA and VariableB with `zap_labels()` from `haven` package. Additionally, it is best practice to use `is.na()` as recommended in comments.

```
install.packages("haven")
library(haven)

Test2 %>% zap_labels() %>% mutate(Variable1 = case_when
       (VariableA == 1 & VariableB ==1 ~ result.y,
         VariableA == 1 & VariableB ==2 ~ result.y,
         VariableA == 2 & VariableB ==1 ~ result.y,
         VariableA == 2 & VariableB ==2 ~ result.x,
         VariableA == 2 & is.na(VariableB) ~ result.x,
         is.na(VariableA) & VariableB ==1 ~ result.y,
         is.na(VariableA) & VariableB ==2 ~ result.y,
         is.na(VariableA) & is.na(VariableB) ~ result.x,
       ))

# A tibble: 6 × 5
  VariableA VariableB result.x       result.y Variable1     
      <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>          <chr>    <chr>         
1        NA        NA vaild postcode NA       vaild postcode
2        NA        NA vaild postcode NA       vaild postcode
3         2         2 vaild postcode NA       vaild postcode
4        NA        NA vaild postcode NA       vaild postcode
5         2         2 vaild postcode NA       vaild postcode
6         2        NA vaild postcode NA       vaild postcode
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this. Much appreciated :)